# Comments are always wrong -- right, or no?

Tags: documentation, comments

Randomly ran across this [blog](http://alifeprogramming.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/comments-are-always-wrong/) on how one should never read comments, and thought to myself all the comments I've read that were either wrong, dated, or simply confusing. Should one simple never read comments and/or just use regex replace pattern to delete... :-) ...just kidding, but really, maybe not. At the very least seems like comments and the related code should be have timestamps. Agree, or no?

FYI, blog appears to be by this stackoverflow user: [**Nosredna**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61027/nosredna)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An inaccurate comment is just as serious of a bug as wrong code. If it is a persistent problem, I would say the project has serious issues. Big projects such as PostgreSQL (94M uncompressed in src directory) rely on accurate comments to help programmers understand things quickly. They also take comments very seriously.

edit:

Also, if *you* can not summarize what your function is doing, then who can? After you are done writing a function, writing the comment for it can be a test that you fully understand what is going on. If things are still a little muddy in your mind, it will become very apparent when you try write the comment. And this a good thing, that shows what still needs to be worked on.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the feedback, and the reference to a code base that massive and public as a point of reference. Also, since you reference PostgreSQL, which appears to use GIT -- does get support pairing comments to code, and allow for a control that requires comments to be signed off on as being current if the related code is updated? Thanks!

Comment: They just moved to GIT a month or two ago from CVS. When a person commits code changes they are responsible to see that comments above the function are still up to date with actual code. Bug reports can be filed against code, comments, and docs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, what I expected, but just wanted to make sure. Selecting you as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

In the real world, programming does not just mean writing code. It means writing code that another programmer (or yourself, in 3 months time) can understand and maintain efficiently.

Any programmer who tells you that comments/documentation are not worth the time it takes to write/maintain them has a number of problems:

- His long term work rate (and that of any colleagues who have to work with his code) *will be lower* than it could be. People *will* waste a lot of time understanding code that could be described in a quick sentence.
- Bug rates relating to his code *will be higher* than they could be, because all those assumptions and special cases that he forgot to mention will constantly trip people up. (How many times have you had to do something "unusual" in your code to make something work, forgotten to comment it to say why you did it that way, and then later on thought it looked like a bug and "fixed" it, only to find that you've broken things horribly because of a subtlety you didn't remember?)
- If he is too lazy to write down how his code works or should be used, what other shortcuts is he taking? Does he bother to check for nulls and handle exceptions? Does he care about his interfaces being consistent? Will he bother to refactor the name of a method/variable if its underlying meaning changes? Usually bad commenting is just the tip of the iceberg.
- Many such programmers are too focussed on "the cool stuff" (like optimising every last cycle out of their code, or finding a clever way to obfuscate a seemingly simple piece of code into a mindboggling template) to understand commercial realities (e.g. he may have trouble getting his code working and shipped to deadlines because he focusses on squeezing unnecessary performance out of it rather than just getting the job done)
- How good are his designs? I do most of my design and thinking when I write down docs/comments. By trying to explain things to the reader of my comments, I flush out a lot of flaws and assumptions that I otherwise would miss. I would go so far as to say that I usually write comments (my intent/design) and then sync the code with them. In most cases if there is a bug in my code, it is the *code* that is wrong *not the comment*.
- He has not realised that by using good variable naming, well designed naming prefixes/conventions, and documentation comments, he can make much better use of fabulous time-saving features of his IDE (auto-complete, intellisense help, etc), and code much faster, with lower defect rates.

Fundamentally, he probably doesn't understand how to write good comments:

1) Comments should act as a quick-read *summary* of a chunk of code. I can read one brief line of text instead of having to work out the meaning of many lines of code. If you find yourself reading the code to navigate it, it is poorly commented. I read the comments to navigate and understand the code, and I only read the code itself when I actually need to work on that specific bit of it.

2) Method/Class comments should describe to a caller everything they need to know to use that class, without having to look inside the "black box" of the code implementation. They will be able to quickly grasp how to use the class/method, and understand all the side effects and the "contract" that an API provides - what can be null and what must be supplied, and which exceptions will be thrown, etc. If you have to read the code to get this, it's either badly encapsulated or badly documented.

3) Use tools like my [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com) addin or Submain's [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx), which mean that his documentation comments can be kept in sync with the code with very little effort.

Comment: +1, wow, thanks -- a lot to take in. Took a quick look at AtomineerUtils/GhostDoc thanks. Guess I've always seen questions about what to document, not how to document; for example: above/inline, timestamp, name, etc. You really did write up a lot, when I've got a sec to take it all in, I'll reply some more, again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Code comments can sometimes be invaluable. Many times I've struggled to determine the intent of code unsuccessfully. For code of any complexity, it can be helpful if the author documents their intent. Of course, well written unit tests can make intent clear as well.

Comment: Yep, I agree, though the question did get me thinking about how nonfunctional based on my understanding version control systems are when it comes to bundling comments to code and enforcing current updates to code and the related comments. Have an example of how unit testing can make the intent of code more clear. In fact, only done ad-hoc (meaning without a framework) unit testing. Very interested in unit testing though.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't write a whole lot of comments, but common types of comments I do write are:

- (sketch) proofs that my code is correct
- explanations why not to just do the obvious thing (e.g: optimization was required, the API I'm calling is shockingly misleading, the "obvious thing" led to a subtle bug)
- a description of the input edge-case which necessitates special handling, thus explaining why the special handling code appears
- a reference to the requirement or specification which mandates the behaviour implemented by a particular line of code
- top-level description of a series of steps taken: ("first get the input", "now strip the wrapper", "finally parse it"), which aren't needed if the names of the functions called for each step are well-chosen and unambiguous in context, but I'm not going to write a do-nothing wrapper for a generic function just to give it a more specific name for one single use
- documentation to be extracted automatically. This is a large proportion of comments by volume, but I'm not sure it "really counts".
- things that *could* be part of the documented interface, but aren't because they might need to change in future, or because they're internal helper stuff that outsiders don't need. Hence, useful for the implementer to be aware of, but not for the user. Private class invariants are included in this - do you really want to read through the whole class every time you want to rely on "this member is non-null", or "size is no greater than capacity", or "access to this member must be synchronized"? Better to check the description of the member before assigning to it, to see whether you're allowed to. If someone doesn't have the discipline to avoid breaking a clearly commented invariant, well, no wonder all their comments are wrong...

Some of those things are handled by comprehensive tests, in the sense that if the tests pass then the code is correct (hah), if you have the test code open too then you can see the special input cases, and if some fool hides the comments, makes the same mistake I originally did, and refactors my code to do the obvious thing, then the tests will fail. That doesn't mean comments don't handle it *better*, in the context of reading through code. In none of these cases is reading the comment a substitute for reading the code, they're designed to highlight what's important but not obvious.

Of course in the case of auto-docs, it's perfectly reasonable, and probably more usable, to view the documentation separately.

When debugging, as opposed to making changes, it's *way* more valuable to let the code explain itself. Comments are less useful, especially those private invariants, because if you're debugging then there's a reasonable chance that whoever wrote the code+comments made a mistake, so the comments may well be wrong. On the plus side, if you see a comment that doesn't reflect what the code does, there's a reasonable chance you've found a bug. If you just see what the code does, it might be some time before you realise that what the code does isn't what it's supposed to do.

Sometimes good naming goes a long way towards replacing comments. However, names can be just as misleading as comments if they're wrong. And, let's be honest, frequently names are at least slightly misleading or ambiguous. I doubt that the author of that blog post would go to the extent of replacing all names with "var1, var2, func1, func2, class1, class2 ...", just to make sure that they weren't distracted by the original author's incorrect intentions for the code. And I don't think it's any truer to say that "comments are always wrong" than to say that "variable names are always wrong". They're written by the same person at the same time with the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments are useful and good, other comments are not.

Yes, comments and code should be timestamped, but you shouldn't timestamp it yourself.  Your source control system should manage this for you, and you should be able to access this information (e.g. using `cvs annotate` or `svn blame`).

Comment: Never used a source control system, guessing you use SVN; guessing this based on your use of the "blame" command. If so, does SVN auto-pair comments to code and independently timestamp each based on the last edit?

Comment: I have used many source control systems, most recently TFS.  The annotate is not to pair comments with code, it's to tell you when each line of code was last modified and who modified it.

Comment: Seems like it would auto-paired, and that you could turn on a rule that would require updates to code that have related comments to be signed off on as being current before the code was committed. What do you think?

Comment: No; you put comments that describe the code alongside the code in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

Comment *why* you are doing something and not what you did syntactically.